# memoir class and \titleGM title page style with custom dimensions

Tags: margins, memoir

I'm attempting to format a textbook that I'm writing using the memoir document class and am running into some problems with the `memoir` class and the `\titleGM` custom title page style.

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[9pt,extrafontsizes,oneside]{memoir}

\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settypeblocksize{7.5in}{4.5in}{*}
\setlrmargins{0.75in}{*}{*}

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}

\fixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Font and Typography Settings

\usepackage{concrete}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
```

And here is the definition of the `\titleGM` command that I'm attempting to use:

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\drop
\newcommand*{\titleGM}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup% Gentle Madness
\drop = 0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vfill
\hbox{%
\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-28pt\relax}%
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth}% 
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{%
\vbox{%
    \vspace{\drop}
    {\Huge\bfseries\raggedright\@title\par}\vskip2.37\baselineskip
    {\Large\bfseries\@author\par}
    \vspace{0.5\textheight}
}% end of vbox
}% end of parbox
}% end of hbox
\vfill
\null
\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

The problem that I seem to be having is that the title page drops off the bottom (the vertical line goes down into the margin, and the title page doesn't seem to fit the text dimensions very well. Does anyone know how to modify this titlepage style?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that with your current settings, a portion of the text area lies outside the physical page; this can be seen with the help of the `showframe` package (it draws some visual guides); loading this package with your settings, one gets

[image]

and you can see that the text area is wrong. You need to adjust your settings; one possibility is to use the predefined stock and page sizes offered by the class (pages); for example, with `mediumvopaper`  and `\pagemediumvo`

```
\documentclass[9pt,extrafontsizes,oneside,mediumvopaper]{memoir}

\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setlrmargins{0.75in}{*}{*}
\pagemediumvo

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}

\fixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

% Font and Typography Settings

\usepackage{concrete}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\makeatletter
\newlength\drop
\newcommand*{\titleGM}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup% Gentle Madness
\drop = 0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vfill
\hbox{%
\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-28pt\relax}%
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth}% 
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{%
\vbox{%
    \vspace{\drop}
    {\Huge\bfseries\raggedright\@title\par}\vskip2.37\baselineskip
    {\Large\bfseries\@author\par}
    \vspace{0.5\textheight}
}% end of vbox
}% end of parbox
}% end of hbox
\vfill
\null
\endgroup}
\makeatother

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\titleGM

\end{document}
```

[image]

The mediumvo options will give you `9in` x `5.75in`; if you want to have `9in` x `6in`, you could use the following settings:

```
\documentclass[9pt,extrafontsizes,oneside,mediumvopaper]{memoir}

\stockheight=9in
\stockwidth=6in
\paperheight=9in     
\paperwidth=6in
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setlrmargins{0.75in}{*}{*}
```

Comment: Hm, that's not quite what I'm going for - I'm trying to mimic to some extent the style of old-school programming textbooks like "How to Solve it by Computer" by R.G. Dromey. The book itself is 9in x 6in, and with a straight-edge I measured both the right and left margins to be 0.75 inches. Is there anyway to get the title page to work within these parameters?

Comment: @ggelfond I see. Please see my updated answer.